# Real-world SQL Server FILESTREAM advice from experience

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Has anyone implemented SQL Server with `FILESTREAM` in an enterprise business environment with two or more terabytes of file data? Do you have any "lessons learned", especially with regard to backups, recovery, and the development lifecycle (i.e. developers wanting a backup from production without the n terabytes of file data)?

It seems the restrictions on creating the `FILESTREAM` "directory" only when the database is created, and then not being able to attach to it from other databases would pose several problems in a dev/qa/int/prod environment without schlepping the terabytes of files around as well.

I've read several articles on partial or piecemeal restores, and on setting all the binary content to null before backup, etc, but such suggestions would seem to suddenly complicate and bog down the ordinary copy-test-deploy cycle a development shop is used to, and I would imagine others have had the pros and cons discussion before converting to a `FILESTREAM` architecture landscape.